# ESP8266 not able to handle incoming POST request from node.js server

Tags: json, node.js, http, arduino, esp8266

I'm coding a home IoT project. The main server is written in Node.js using Express JS and all of the peripheral devices use ESP8266 to connect to the server over the WiFi network.

What I am trying to accomplish is very simple. One of the components is an RGB lightbulb. User is able to change the lightbulb's color or power (turn it on and off).

In order to change the lightbulb's color I want to send a POST request from the Node.js server to the ESP8266 containing very simple body consisting of something like this:

```
{"red" : 255, "green" : 128, "blue" : 0}
```

To send the request from the Node.js server I use the `request` npm package. Request looks like this:

```
const options = {
        url: 'http://192.168.1.226:80/changeBulbColor',
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            "red": 255,
            "green": 255,
            "blue": 255
        },
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    };

    request(options, callback);
```

I also tried a version of the request where I switched `json` to `body` and added an additional field `json: true`.

When I tried sending the request using `curl` everything was fine. This is the curl command that worked:

```
curl -vv -X POST -d "{"power":false}" "Content-Type: application/json" http://192.168.1.226/changeBulbPower
```

When I tried using the `request` library and send the POST from the Node.js server, `body` that comes to ESP8266 is always empty. When I tried to log the number of body's arguments' I got 0.

The ESP8266's code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "password";

bool isOn = false;
const int redPin = 0;
const int bluePin = 1;
const int greenPin = 2;

struct Color {
  int R;
  int G;
  int B;
};

bool isInSetupMode = false;

Color* bulbColor;

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void handleRoot() {
    String response = "<html><head></head><body>";
    response+= "Lightbulb is ";
    response+= ((isOn == 1) ? "on" : "off");
    response += "</br>";
    response += "Value of red: " + String (bulbColor -> R );
    response += "</br>Value of green: " + String (bulbColor -> G );
    response += "</br>Value of blue: " + String (bulbColor -> B );
    IPAddress myIP = WiFi.localIP();
    response+= "<br> Device's IP address: ";
    response+= String(myIP[0]);
    response+= ".";
    response+= String(myIP[1]);
    response+= ".";
    response+= String(myIP[2]);
    response+= ".";
    response+= String(myIP[3]);
    response+= "</body></html>";
    server.send(200,"text/html",response);
}

void handleBulbRequest() {
  Serial.println(server.arg("plain"));
  Serial.println(server.args());  
  for(int i = 0; i < server.args(); i++ ) {
    Serial.print(server.argName(i) + ": ");
    Serial.println(server.arg(i));
  }
  StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(server.arg("plain"));
  if(!root.success()){
    server.send(400);
    return;
  }

  bulbColor->R = root["red"];
  bulbColor->G = root["green"];
  bulbColor->B = root["blue"];
  if(isOn) {
    analogWrite(redPin, bulbColor->R);
    analogWrite(greenPin, bulbColor->G);
    analogWrite(bluePin, bulbColor->B);
  }
  server.send(200);
}

void onPowerChange() {
  StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(server.arg("plain"));
  if(!root.success()){
    server.send(400);
    return;
  }

  isOn = root["power"];

  if(isOn) {
    analogWrite(redPin, bulbColor->R);
    analogWrite(greenPin, bulbColor->G);
    analogWrite(bluePin, bulbColor->B);
  } else {
    analogWrite(redPin, 1);
    analogWrite(greenPin, 1);
    analogWrite(bluePin, 1);
  }
  server.send(200);
}

void onAssignDevice() {
  StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(server.arg("plain"));
  if(!root.success()) {
    server.send(400);
    return;
  }
  isInSetupMode = root["highlight"];
  server.send(200);
}

void handleNotFound(){
  String message = "File Not Found\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET)?"GET":"POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<server.args(); i++){
    message += " " + server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
  }
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
}

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(74880);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
  } 

  server.on("/", HTTP_GET , handleRoot);
  server.on("/changeBulbColor", HTTP_POST, handleBulbRequest);
  server.on("/highlightDevice", onAssignDevice);
  server.on("/changeBulbPower", onPowerChange);
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);

  bulbColor = new Color();
  bulbColor->R = 1;
  bulbColor->G = 1;
  bulbColor->B = 1;

  sendMessageToServerDebug();
  server.begin();
}

void loop(void) {
  server.handleClient();
  if(isInSetupMode) {
    digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
    delay(750);
  }
}

void sendMessageToServer() {
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin("http://192.168.43.197:4000/registerDevice"); //HTTP
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.localIP();
  String json = "{\"ip\""" + String(myIP[0]) + "." + String(myIP[1]) + "." + String(myIP[2]) + "." + String(myIP[3]) + "\",";
  json += "\"mac\""";
  json += WiFi.macAddress() + "\",\"deviceType\""LIGHTS\"}";
  int httpCode = http.POST(json);
  if(httpCode > 0) {
    if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
      String payload = http.getString();
    }
  } else {
  }
  http.end();
}

void sendMessageToServerDebug() {
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin("http://192.168.1.79:8080/registerDevice"); //HTTP
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.localIP();
  String json = "{\"ip\""" + String(myIP[0]) + "." + String(myIP[1]) + "." + String(myIP[2]) + "." + String(myIP[3]) + "\",";
  json += "\"mac\""";
  json += WiFi.macAddress() + "\",\"deviceType\""LIGHTS\"}";
  int httpCode = http.POST(json);
  if(httpCode > 0) {
    if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
      String payload = http.getString();
    }
  } else {
  }
  http.end();
}
```

Comment: It might help to see the curl command that works.

Comment: @JimBaldwin I added the command to the post, please check it out

Comment: I suggest adding some code to print out what the response is.  This may tell you something.

Comment: @JimBaldwin I have tried that in the first place as soon as I ran into troubles. I didnt post the `Serial.println`s here, because there is no point in that. As I stated in the post - everything that I tried to print out  (`  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(server.arg("plain"));` this line, all of it's contents altogether and separately) but everything was simply empty. That's why I have no idea what's going on